# What does the BluetoothGATTSetCharacteristicValue ReliableWriteContext parameter actually do?

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Using C++ VS2017 Win10...

I am testing some code to set a characteristic value on a BLE device.  I had originally had the default function call

```
HRESULT hr = BluetoothGATTSetCharacteristicValue(
                hBleService.get(), 
                _pGattCharacteristic, 
                gatt_value, 
                NULL, 
                BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_NONE);
```

I had to switch the flag to BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_WRITE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE to get any sets to take place even though IsWritable and IsReadable were the only 2 properties set showing true but that is a different story and another topic.

Anyway,  before I found the problem with the flag I had tried to use the ReliableWriteContext parameter so the code changed to

```
    HANDLE hDevice = _bleDeviceContext.getBleDeviceHandle();            
    BTH_LE_GATT_RELIABLE_WRITE_CONTEXT ReliableWriteContext = NULL;
    HRESULT hr1 = BluetoothGATTBeginReliableWrite(hDevice,
        &ReliableWriteContext,
        BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_NONE);

    HRESULT hr = BluetoothGATTSetCharacteristicValue(
        hBleService.get(), 
        _pGattCharacteristic, 
        gatt_value, 
        ReliableWriteContext, 
        BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_WRITE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE);

    if (NULL != ReliableWriteContext) {
        BluetoothGATTEndReliableWrite(hDevice,
            ReliableWriteContext,
            BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_NONE);
    }
```

Once I fixed the flag issue my BluetoothGATTSetCharacteristicValue() function would work with either the NULL or the ReliableWriteContext parameters.  No difference that I could see.

My question is,then, what does the ReliableWriteContext do exactly?  MS docs only say:

> The BluetoothGATTBeginReliableWrite function specifies that reliable
> writes are about to begin.

Well that doesn't tell me anything.  So should I keep the reliable writes because the word "**Reliable**" sure sounds like it is something that I want? Or do I not use it because it does not seem to be necessary>

Any insight would be appreciated.

Ed

Comment: It does nothing except tellls to BluetoothGATTSetCharacteristicValue function that is must execute reliable write operation (that is more or less identical to long write but with some additional support on client side). And your call to BluetoothGATTBeginReliableWrite is wrong. You should use service handle instead of device one.

Comment: Mike, thanks for catching that service handle.  The MS docs syntax show hDevice but down in their parameters description that say "Handle to the service". Arggg. I didn't catch that....

So, in your opinion, is it worth having ReliableWrite? Does the "additional support" add something that I would be good to have?

Comment: Actualy no, I'll better stay with just setting WriteWithoutResponse to false. Internally it will be more or less the same.